# looking for idMso for the Access context menu option "edit list items"

Tags: ms-access, vba

This option may be used in case of missing an item in a dropdown menu (combbox) When clicking the option, the lookup-table with options will open for adding the missing item. After closing the lookup-table, the new option will be available in the dropdon menu (combobox)

thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Be clear with your question.

Comment: This what you want http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-27.html ?

Comment: Or this http://www.accessribbon.de/en/?FAQ:1 it has link to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3582

Comment: Cross post http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=68045&p=371132#post371132